# What values are valid for use with ServerName when setting up Apache virtual hosts locally?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm currently setting up Apache virtual hosts for a number of websites I need to develop on localhost. Using the following configuration (and after updating my `/etc/hosts` file), I can access the content stored at `/var/www/example.com/public_html` by going to `example.com` in my web browser:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**My question:**

Are there rules for choosing values for `ServerName`? For example, must the value I use be a domain name such as `ServerName example.com` or can I omit the `.com` extension and use simply `ServerName example`? Must I use all lowercase characters, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever name you want for local domain. Look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ServerName).

**ServerName Apache**

```
ServerName [scheme://]fully-qualified-domain-name[:port]

The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port 
thatthe server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
redirection URLs.
```

Comment: I'm wondering if that means `ServerName example` is invalid. In my case, that's the value I'd like to use.

Comment: It's perfectly valid, the manual is wrong and I'll change it.  Any host  the client will put in a Host: header is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever is a valid FQDN - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name.

Put that name in `/etc/hosts` as well and get it to use 127.0.0.1.

PS: Make one up that either does not exist in the outside world or even the future intended web site

**EDIT**

Line in /etc/hosts

```
  127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Then

```
 ServerName example.com
```

This will make example.com be on your local machine. Ideal for development. When done all you need to do (assuming example.com has a CNAME) is remove the line from /etc/hosts. You can even do the development off line

Comment: Does that mean to say `ServerName example` is invalid?

Comment: I am not sure - try it. By what is wrong with adding the .com bit

Comment: When I add `.com` it stops me from accessing the live website from my local machine. I get taken to the local development site.

Comment: Any .com address goes to the local machine?

Comment: No. Only example.com

Comment: Thanks for the edit and explanation, but what if I want to access the live production version of example.com from my local machine?

Comment: Remove (or comment out) the line in /etc/hosts

Comment: Right. Do you see now why I don't want to use `.com`? Using `ServerName example.com` will mean my production site is inaccessible (unless I modify /etc/hosts). Modifying /etc/hosts isn't something I want to do each time.

Comment: Why not just make up a different name of development? Then have two different URLs. One live, one development

Comment: No reason aside from having lots of development websites and having to remember all the names I've made up. example.com -> example, test.com -> test, another.com -> another, foo.com -> foo all kinda make sense.

Comment: Perhaps `example.com` - live, `dev.example.com` - Development. Ditto for the others. Quite simple

Comment: Yeah, think that's going to be my approach. Still going to keep an eye out for the answer here though, now it's grabbed my interest :)

It may well end up that `ServerName example` isn't valid, but I'd like to know for sure. 

Thanks for your help

Comment: As an aside, have you got the values in your `/etc/hosts` file the wrong way round?

Comment: Yes - You are right. I just usually look at the previous contents to get that bit right

Answer (score 0):

The `ServerName` setting has two purposes:

1. along with the port in the `<VirtualHost>` declaration, help Apache match the request to a virtualhost, based on the incoming `Host:` request header. A virtualhost will be used to serve a request if the contents of the `Host:` header matches the `ServerName` or one of the `ServerAlias`es of the virtualhost, AND the request arrived on the port specified in the `<VirtualHost>` declaration. (If the HTTP verb is follwed by a full URL instead of just a path, e.g. `GET http://example.com/index.html HTTP/1.1`, then the hostname portion of the URL can also be used for virtualhost matching, not just the `Host` header.) If there is no match with any virtualhost, the default virtualhost gets served. The default is the one that occurs first in the configuration. As long as you can get clients to a) talk to your server at all and b) put the same string in a `Hosts:` header when they do, any ServerName is "valid" for this use of the ServerName, but not the second:
2. Depending on the value of [`UseCanonicalName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname), the `ServerName` will be used in outgoing `Location:` response headers when generating redirects. (If `UseCanonicalName` is off, the `Location` header will reference the same hostname that the client used when making the request.) The `Location:` header [must contain](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-14.30) a valid [absolute URI](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2396), which rules out completely arbitrary strings for ServerNames (but just "example", without ".com", would be technically fine, as long as your clients can be made to understand it's a fully qualified domain name and that no further qualification, e.g. by appending suffixes from the domain search list, should be attempted).

While you can really use almost any string as a ServerName, it's probably only useful to use ServerNames that the clients you care about will actually use when talking to your server; that is, when the clients look up your ServerName using whatever mechanism they use to translate names to IP addresses (in almost all cases, this will be `/etc/hosts` followed by DNS if the first lookup fails), they should see an IP they can reach your server on. (The ServerName can also be an IP address itself.)

Since ServerNames are considered to be domain names (in the DNS sense), they should be case insensitive.